# How to collect variables from a URL, insert them into an array and dynamically change a href URLs?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, onclick, href

How to collect variables from a URL, insert them into an array and dynamically change a href URLs?

I'm not a developer so please be easy on me here!  I am familiar with HTML and not bad at taking snippets of code from various sources and cobbling them together.  This is the first time, I've ever decided to reach out for help on a blog like this because I've been looking around and just can't seem to find exactly what I need.  Very close and yet so far..  Please help!

What I want to do is:

1. collect variables from the URL like this (`wwww.myurl.com/index.html?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3` etc. etc..)
2. Take those variables and insert them into an array while stripping out the un-needed parts.  I found this code which gets it but prints it on the screen, which I don't need..

   ```
   myurl.com/index.html?log=1&pass=2
   ```

   ```
   function addComment()
   {
       var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

       var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
       l = unescape(temp[1]);

       temp = parameters[1].split("=");
       c = unescape(temp[1]);

       document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = l;
       document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = c;
   }
   addComment();


   <p>http://www.myurl.com/</b><span id="log" ></span></p>
   <p>http://www.myurl.com/</b><span id="pass"></span></p>

   </script>
   ```
3. Dynamically alter a href tags on the fly based on the parameters gathered from the URL.

I found this code which works great to alter the URLs but (a) the variable is gathered from an input form and I need to be able to take them from the URL.  (b) I also need several of them (could be like 20) so an array is needed.

```
<input type="text" id="mySearchBox" />
<a href="http://www.myurl.com/index.html?" onclick="this.href+=+document.getElementById('mySearchBox').value">Enter Parameter</a>
```

(edited code format)

---

Regarding the technology... I'm not stuck on any particular language or method but javascript and the jquery seems to be the easiest for me.  I haven't done much with **PHP** and other languages.  The easiest method for dummies you can provide the better.

I'm sure this is like elementary school stuff to you out there but I just can't seem to figure it out so your advice is much appreciated!

Comment: The blog stripped out some of the code that I pasted in here so it is missing.  Hopefully the description I provided will be enough to respond to.  If not, I'll figure out how to paste it in here with the brackets to get it to be displayed...

Comment: Just pasted it, there are editors who will format it.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you add this part too?  It was the part where it says "Enter Parameter"..  <input type="text" id="mySearchBox" />
<a href="http://www.myurl.com/index.html?" onclick="this.href+=+document.getElementById('mySearchBox').value">Enter Parameter</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript & jQuery**

The first line of the addComment function gets the searchsrtring from the url, wich is everething from (and with) the ? up to (and without) the hash (#) or the end if there is no hash.

After that the first character (?) is removed with `substr(1)`. Finally the string is split at every "&" with `.split("&")`. All the splited parts are stored in an array. Applying this on an example:

`www.myurl.com/index.html?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3`

Becomes

`["var1=1", "var2=2", "var3=3"]`

this array is stored in the variable parameters.
Next the first element of the array is splitted at the "=" character.
We get

`temp = ["var1", "1"]`

the second element of temp is unescaped ( to decode special characters from the url like %20 to " " (space) )

To create an object of that, first create an empty object and then fill it like this:

`var obj = {};`

`obj[ temp[0] ] = temp[1];`

Doing this on a for loop with all the elements from parameters will get you:

`obj = { var1 : 1, var2 : 2, var3 : 3 }`

The object that you wanted. This is a very simple parser and may not work properly for more complex values.
This is the full code described above:

```
function getUrlObj() {
  var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
  var obj = {};
  for( var i = 0; i < parameters.length; ++i) {
    var tmp = parameters[i].split("=");
    obj[ tmp[0] ] = unescape( tmp[1] );
  }
  return obj
}
```

now to the links:

with your example the onclick event of the link decides which url is loaded. Like this the status bar of the browser will not show the correct destination which is more difficult to debug and less user friendly. A different approach (with jQuery) would be to collect all links from the page and change their href tags according to the url.
This can be done after the page (or better the DOM) has been loaded. a jquery example may look like this:

```
$( function() { //called when dom is ready
  //get url object
  var urlObj = getUrlObj();
  //find all <a> elements on page
  // iterate over elements
  $('a').each(function() {
    // change attribute href
    $(this).attr('href', 'new url goes here');
  });
});
```

I guess you want to insert some parts of the url object in the new url. what is the initial value of the href attribute? what should it look like in the end?

The initial value may indicate how the url must be changed. The value of an attribute can be accessed with the method `.attr('href')` in jquery (a second argument would change the value).

a detailed explanation of the `.attr()` method (and others) can be found in the jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

if you don't want to change all the link elements you may apply a class to the links you want to modify like:

`<a class="modify" href...`

and then acces those elements with
`$('.modify')` (with dot) instead of `$('a')`.

**PHP**

If you want to do it with php the code might be a lot simpler because php can handle the url querystring natively. Example:

`<a href="<?php echo $_GET["var1"]; ?>.php">link</a>`

will result in a link to "1.php" with your example.

**UPDATE**: (according to the discussion in the comments)

The search query `?iframe1=1&banner1=1&button1=1&button2=2&button3=3` is sent to the server along with the url. PHP can access the values of the search query directly via the magic [variable `$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) as pointed out above. $_GET['button1'] will be 1.

To use the variable the file ending has to be .php so the server knows that the contents of the file have to be evaluated. The resulting file will be a normal html file (with php ending).

writing `<?php` indicates that the following text up to `?>` is php code. `echo "something";` will print the string `something` into the resulting html file.
A shortcut for printing something to the document is `<?="text" ?>`. Instead of a string a variable can be printed: `<?=$somevar ?>`.

Applying this to the example the html file has to updated something like this:

```
<a target="theiframe" href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?<?=$_GET['button1'] ?>">a link</a>
<a target="theiframe" href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?<?=$_GET['button2'] ?>">another link</a>
```

and so on. Same for the iframe (or the banner):

```
<iframe name="theiframe" src="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?<?=$_GET['iframe1'] ?>"/>
```

Another (better) way of combining all the html files into one php file would be to have a number or a string that represents a page. e.g. `?page=somepage` (try to avoid special characters and spaces, they might not work properly).

In the php file there will then be a switch for all the pages:

```
<?php if( $_GET['page'] == "somepage" ) { ?>
  <a target="theiframe" href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?1">a link</a>
  <a target="theiframe" href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?2">another link</a>
<?php } elseif( $_GET['page'] == "someotherpage" ) { ?>
  <a target="theiframe" href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?3">a link</a>
  <a target="theiframe" href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?4">another link</a>
<?php } //and so on (btw this is a php comment) ?>
```

The advantages of that approach are:

1. a shorter url
2. in the first approach, if a new button is added later you would have to change all the links to that page, adding a buttonx=x in the url. also the additional button would not work if someone uses a bookmark (with the old url) to navigate to that site.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply!  Love the "pascalfree" UN. LOL :)  I'll take it for a spin in a while after my day j.o.b. and let you know how it goes.  Looks promising and I really appreciate the explanation.  I lied.. should have said 25yrs+ :D

Comment: Ok.  I had a chance to read through this.  That was very helpful to gather the variables. Now I'm left hanging with getting them into those <a> tags. I'm not exactly sure what you mean about how to populate the red parts and my feeble brain can't fill in the dots here.  PHP sounds like an option but the site is all built in JS and I'm wondering whether that would clash.

Comment: I hate to request to be spoon fed here but need a little more help to get to the correct syntax for:

1. <a href="www.myurl.com/index.html?"+'var1'>link1</a>
resulting in the a tag hyperlink www.myurl.com/index.html?2
... or the addition of the <img src="./images/.."> tag so I can link an image to that dynamic URL

2. <iframe src="www.myurl.com/index.html?"+'var2'></iframe>
resulting in the iframe opening for www.myurl.com/index.html?2

Comment: To provide context, this is an example of the type of page I am working on 

http://www.doxietalk.com/doxiecalendars.html

The 3 dynamic objects are:

1. The banner (which will change per breed)
2. The black buttons (all of the URLs are the same. The only thing that changes is the last digits after the "=" (node=x)). 
3. The iFrame on the bottom. Same syntax as the 2nd URL

Comment: The goal is that I only create 1 page and just tweak the variables in the URL to make the topic of the page anything I want.  Currently, I need to make separate pages for every breed and type which is a pain.

Again, my apologies for being thick here! Thank you..

Comment: @user1676274 php and javascript can't clash because they are executed in different places and times. Php is executed server-side. When the Page shows up in the browser, javascript gets started client-side. If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to always load the same page with some small modifications indicated in the url with: `...index.html?page=x`. the small modifications depend on the x. The links will contain that x somehow, the banner will be different depending on the x and also the initial iFrame link. If so I would strongly recommend using php if your server supports that

Comment: @user1676274 If my assumption is correct the php parts will be small and easy to do. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: As always, thank you so much for your patience and help!
Yes.  It looks as though my provider supports PHP.  I uploaded <?php phpinfo();?> to a file info.php and it shows all of the versions so I think we should be ok.. I'm willing to give it a shot if that will be easiest.

To be very specific, this is what I'm looking to do:

Comment: The input url will be --> www.mysite.com/store.html?iframe1=1&banner1=1&button1=1&button2=2&button3=3 etc. etc. etc..

(iframe1 is the default iframe view e.g. 1=Boxer, 2=Dachsund, 3=Poodle etc but the system doesn't need to store this information anywhere)
(The buttons represent the filters - 1=Calendars, 2=Books etc) again the system doesn't have to store this information anywhere)

Resulting in

Comment: 1. The links in the black buttons will change to a href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?"+ the value received from button1
or.. a href="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?"+ the value received from button2

2. The iframe generated in that page will be iframe="www.mysite.com/redirect2external?"+ the value received from iframe1

Comment: 3. Top banner a href and img tag with different banner, leading to different pages.  This one is a little tricky because I'm not sure where the banners will link to at this point so we can keep it as a static image link at this point.  Unless you have another idea about that...

Does this make sense??  Really hard to type in these boxes where all the text is jumbled together.. sorry

Comment: @user1676274 Yes it makes sense :-)
I've updated my answer. You may also update your question in order to have a better formatted text than in the comments.

Comment: OMG!  Holy $hi+ stx!  It works!!  I can't believe how simple and effective that was and all the time I spent trying to figure it out.  You rock!  Now before we close... I just have another hopefully quick question.

Comment: I didn't even have the courage to try the second option yet.  Maybe that will make things much easier but how can I insert my own variables in there for the img tag and img a tag?  For example.  What if I want to do

Comment: Simple img only <img src="mysite.com/images/=$_GET['banner1'] ?>.jpg"/>
.... where banner1=banner1.jpg?  I tried to enter the value banner1.jpg in the URL and it got tripped up.  Then I tried to just enter banner and put the .jpg on the end but it didn't understand that.

The same for the combined a href + img combo tag.

We're almost there :)

Comment: @user1676274 the code you wrote is missing a `<?` before `=$_GET...`. If this is not the problem, inspect the sourcecode of your page and write here how it looks where the banner image name should be.

Comment: SUCCESS!  Thank you for everything.  I really appreciate it.  Although I have a feeling some more scenarios will pop up, this appears to be closure for now.. Please drop by the site sometime in the near future to see your solution implemented :)  doxiestuff>con.us for a proper thx

Comment: @user1676274 I'm glad I could help :-). Please don't forget to accept my answer above (by ticking it beneath the vote count on the top left of the answer). thx

Answer (score 1):

Great jQuery plugin for reading and modification of query strings: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

Just use it to get job done or examine it's source to get answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I just had a quick look at that site and it does look informative.  I will read up on it but was hoping to have someone either fix what I have so far or provide the best approach.  Over time, I will try to brush up on my skills but the boat to being a developer sailed off about 20 years ago when I used to know Fortran, Pascal, and Basic. lol