# Is it possible to serve a html or php file with Sinatra, and be able to process url variables?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have the following ruby sinatra code that I'm trying to get to serve a dynamic page that I want to send URL variables to, for instance to produce a page specific to a `user_id`.

It's worth noting that the customisation of the page happens entirely in javascript, so the page can be html.

```
get '/page/:user_id' do
    File.read(File.join('dynamic_pages', "page.html"))
end
```

I believe sinatra can't host php so I've been trying with html URL variables that are caught and parsed with javascript, but I can't figure the sinatra hosting and parsing of url variables out.

This is only one small page on a service that's mainly a sinatra API, so I would like to avoid running another server type if there's a more work involved, but that's always an option!

Answer (score 0):

Your post really makes no sense to me, but here goes:

> html URL variables

There's no such thing.  A url has nothing to do with html.

> I can't figure the parsing of url variables out.

The colon names are available in the params hash:

```
get '/page/:user_id' do
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    ...
end
```

**Response to comment:**

```
get '/page/:user_id' do
    user_id = params[:user_id]

    redirect to(
      "page.html?userid=#{user_id}"
    )
end
```

By default, Sinatra will look for that page in `your_app_dir/public` directory.  The javascript on the html page can then get the query string and parse out the variables, e.g.:

```
  <script>
    var query_str = location.search.substr(1);
    var i = 0;
    var names_values = query_str.split('&');
    var len = names_values.length

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      var name_value = names_values[i].split('=');
      console.log(name_value[0] + " => " + name_value[1]);
    }

  </script>

--console output:--
userid => 1
color => red
```

Comment: To clarify.. `HTML URL Variables` [see this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451258/how-to-collect-variables-from-a-url-insert-them-into-an-array-and-dynamically-c), and I'm referring to them as HTML URL variables to differentiate them from PHP URL variables. Also, I'm familiar with `params[]` but the issue is that if you're trying to host a file at a given path, as my code is doing, you cannot append URL variables to the end of the path as the `File.read` claims the path doesn't exist given the addition of the URL variables to the path. Does that make more sense?

Comment: For further clarification, I want to be able to serve a get for `/page/:user_id` and the user to be sent to `page.html?userid=1` where 1 is the :user_id value

Comment: @Ian, I amended my answer in response to your comment in regards to your Sinatra and query strings question.